How to configure ssh in ec2 (AWS) machine with ubuntu 24 to ask for pem and password when a ssh connection is requested?
It is a fresh ec2 instancia in which I've only set a password for ubuntu user.
I have tried different combinations in sshd_config file (without a strong criteria) but have not been successful.

The issue was related to the include sentence in ssd_config:
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf

In distribtions prior to Ubuntu 24 there was no any file in that location by default, but in Ubuntu 24 there is a file called 60-cloudimg-settings.conf with the following content:
PasswordAuthentication no

This was originating all my configuration problems.
